# Unit of work is driven by external event. How to ensure one unit starts only after the previous one ends?

Tags: python, twisted, python-2.6

I am not sure how to refactor my app. I have read something about ChainedDefered, but I am lost at how to apply the technique to my situation. Any pointer/suggestions are welcome.

I am using a third party library to monitor some external data source which changes very rapidly in real time. Whenever a change is detected, the library will call a callback function in my code. My callback function will in turn retrieve data from database and perform some processing.

```
class MyApp(object):
    def start(self):
        for i in range(1, 1000):
            mycallback = CallBackHandler(x, y, z)
            thirdPartyLib.subscribe(event_name + str(i), mycallback)

     reactor.start()


class CallBackHandler(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
         ....

    def getSomeDataAndDoSomething(self):
        ...

    def __call__(self)
       callLater(self.getSomeDataAndDoSomething)
```

The problem is that the CallBackHandler can be called consecutively for numerous times when events happen rapidly in a very short interval. If these callbacks are executed more or less simultaneously, they will produce identical result.

How can I fire the callback iff the last callback has finished processing? I'd prefer to use constructs offered in twisted to achieve it instead of, says, by comparing timestamps of events (so drop callback if it has been fired 1 sec before) or a global variable as flag.

Answer (score 1):

In the future, please [include complete code samples](http://sscce.org).

If you want to execute something `Deferred`-returning with a limited level of concurrency, Twisted includes a class called [`DeferredSemaphore`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.defer.DeferredSemaphore.html) that you can use.

In 2006, Jean-Paul Calderone wrote a great [blog post about how to limit parallelism with it](http://as.ynchrono.us/2006/05/limiting-parallelism_22.html).